# Who SSH'd into User using auth.log/RSA Key

Tags: key-authentication

Ubuntu 14.04:
Using the auth.log im able to see: accepted publickey for $user from 192.168.xx.xx port xxxxx ssh2: RSA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

Using that RSA Key how do i know which public key it is in /home/$user/.ssh/authorized_keys

/home/$user/.ssh/authorized_keys are not in hexadecimal format which is what im guessing the RSA key format is in auth.log???

Comment: I believe the `auth.log` only shows the key _fingerprint_, not the key itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the `auth.log` entries show the public key fingerprint and not the key itself.

You can compare the fingerprints in the `auth.log` file with the fingerprint of the keys listed in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` by using the `ssh-keygen -E -lf` command.

The `-E` option allows you to set the hash as either MD5 or SHA256.  The `-lf` option shows the fingerprint of a public key file.  The colon separated hash is the MD5 form.

You can copy the public keys from the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file and store the them in individual text files.  From there, it's easy to get the hashes of each public key.

```
ssh-keygen -E MD5 -lf pkey.txt
```

The public key is the entire line starting with `ssh-` and ending with the key identifier.

Comment: The copy to `pkey.txt` isn't strictly necessary, since the command doesn't alter the file?

Comment: to clarify the last comment, I just did `ssh-keygen -E MD5 -lf ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and it just shows the fingerprint for each key