# How to log all SSH activity on server with user's hostname or User name?

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, openssh

I have an Ubuntu server and I want to log all SSH activity on my server.

For this, I found one good document here: [How to log all Bash commands by all users on a server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93566/how-to-log-all-bash-commands-by-all-users-on-a-server) I followed this document and enable the logging on the server. I log the commands with the following line:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug "$(whoami) [$$]: $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//" ) [$RETRN_VAL]"
```

It gives the log of all executed command on my server (locally executed and SSHed).I have attached the output of the same.

What I need is, In the log file there should be a username or the hostname and public IP address of the user who used to connect to my local server.

Does anybody have an idea about this?

Output log file:

```
Aug 7 11:03:34 local ajay: ajay [1906]: sudo rm -rf commands.log*
Aug 7 11:03:36 local ajay: ajay [1906]: ll
Aug 7 11:03:59 local ajay: ajay [1906]: sudo rm -rf messages*
Aug 7 11:04:19 local ajay: ajay [1906]: sudo rm -rf usercommands
Aug 7 11:04:49 local ajay: ajay [1906]: sudo rm -rf history.log
Aug 7 11:05:11 local ajay: ajay [1906]: ll
Aug 7 11:05:21 local ajay: ajay [1906]: cat commands.log
Aug 7 11:05:33 local ajay: ajay [1906]: cat commands.log
Aug 7 11:05:46 local ajay: ajay [1906]: sudo chmod -R 777 commands.log
Aug 7 11:05:48 local ajay: ajay [1906]: cat commands.log
Aug 7 11:06:19 local ajay: ajay [1906]: cat commands.log
```

Comment: Did you try the command `last` ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. It gives only the public IP address of last connected users. Is it possible to know Username or hostname with executed command?

Comment: Don't fool yourself, this doesn't log commands executed by SFTP. And anything in a script|alias|function is also hidden. To see who logged on with SSH, check /var/log/auth.log. If you don't trust your users, don't give them access, or chroot them...

Comment: Also if you use key-based authentication, you can tell which key was used to login (ie, the real user, even if ids are shared on the server). See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410265/who-sshd-into-user-using-auth-log-rsa-key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable $SSH_CONNECTION gives you the ports and source/destination IP addresses used by the user connection. So add it as argument to your logger command.

As in:

```
 export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug "$SSH_CONNECTION $(whoami) [$$]: $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//" ) [$RETRN_VAL]"
```

For further details, have a look at [What are SSH_TTY and SSH_CONNECTION?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120080/what-are-ssh-tty-and-ssh-connection)

As for the hostname, that is dependent on DNS resolution. You can always script for solving the reverse DNS of the logs. There is no directive I am aware of  that solves directly to the DNS name.

Comment: What should I do to know the **hostname** of the user who has accessed my server through SSH?

Comment: Ha, good one, forgot that detail. I am aware of a directive, and I would not try to do that in real time due to possible network delays.